# is there a way to provide a function to ruleorder?

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

Is possible to provide a function to ruleorder, like this?

```
def determine_ruleorder(wildcards, config):
    samples_file = pd.read_table(config['sample_file'], sep='\t')
    sample_layout = samples_file.loc[samples_file['sample'] == wildcards.sra, 'layout'].values[0]
    
    if sample_layout == "single":
        return "fasterq_dump_se > fasterq_dump_pe"
    elif sample_layout == "paired":
        return "fasterq_dump_pe > fasterq_dump_se"
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown sample type for SRA '{wildcards.sra}': {sample_layout}")

ruleorder: determine_ruleorder
```

In this case, I'm getting the error:

```
UnknownRuleException:
Error in ruleorder definition. There is no rule named determine_ruleorder
```

this would be the sample file:

```
sample  layout
SRR6308266  paired
SRR1525658  single
SRR6308195  paired
SRR6206507  paired
SRR22957809 paired
SRR22957815 paired
SRR21169022 paired
SRR13066396 paired
SRR7904254  paired
SRR6308265  paired
SRR1525659  single
SRR1525660  single
```

Comment: You could generate the snakefile as a separate build step

Answer (score 0):

Seems like no.  Rule order affects the global execution of a workflow while input functions require a single wildcard to evaluate so it seems unlikely it will be implemented.

However, you don't need to in this case.  If an input function raises a value error the next plausible rule is tried:

```
ruleorder:
    dump_se > dump_pe

def dump_se_input(wildcards):
    samples_file = pd.read_table(config['sample_file'], sep='\t')
    sample_layout = samples_file.loc[samples_file['sample'] == wildcards.sra, 'layout'].values[0]
    
    if sample_layout == "single":
        return FILES
    raise ValueError("May be paired")

rule dump_se:
    input: dump_se_input
    ...

def dump_pe_input(wildcards):
    samples_file = pd.read_table(config['sample_file'], sep='\t')
    sample_layout = samples_file.loc[samples_file['sample'] == wildcards.sra, 'layout'].values[0]
    
    if sample_layout == "paired":
        return FILES
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown sample type for SRA '{wildcards.sra}': {sample_layout}")

rule dump_pe:
    input: dump_pe_input
    ...
```

So samples first are evaluated against the SE rule.  If they are paired, the value error causes the PE rule to run.  That also has a check which will raise an (uncaught) error that will alert the user the sample doesn't conform.